# Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios9

I am learning to implement TableView with Search Bar and data filtering. So, I have the following in my `storyboard`:

[image]

My `UITableViewController` is connected to the following `SearchTableViewController.swift` class like this:

```
import UIKit

class SearchTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    // table view controller properties
    let appleProducts = ["Mac", "iPhone", "Apple Watch", "iMac", "iPad"]
    var filteredAppleProducts = [String]()
    var resultSearchController = UISearchController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Configure result search controller
        self.resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        self.resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        self.resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        self.resultSearchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Products"
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.resultSearchController.searchBar
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
            return self.filteredAppleProducts.count
        } else {
            return self.appleProducts.count
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
            cell.textLabel?.text = self.filteredAppleProducts[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = self.appleProducts[indexPath.row]
        }

        return cell
    }

    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        self.filteredAppleProducts.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
        let resultArray = (self.appleProducts as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
        self.filteredAppleProducts = resultArray as! [String]
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

This runs fine and filtering is working as expected:

[image]

However, when the app is running in the simulator, I get the following warning in the debug window:

> 2015-09-07 00:02:46.116 TableViewSearch[2415:68217] Attempting to load
>   the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed
>   and may result in undefined behavior ()

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: What exactly is `TableViewSearch`?

Comment: @ILikeTau it's the name of the project/app in XCode.

Comment: Are you presenting a new controller ? My guess is that it's trying to present this controller again or something similar... Can you add more code ?

Comment: I have had this message. The cause for me was that I had too many Navigation Controllers in the stack. For each storyboard now, I have a Nav. controller for the initial ViewController, but no other NC in that storyboard. Hope this gives you a lead.

Answer (score 6):

I spent all day to understand this problem too... Some said it's related to Navigation Controller issue and others said it's a glitch. Although this may not be the correct answer, hope I can give some hint. If you think it's not a correct approach, let me know. Thanks.
My case is as follows instead (because of a different design, I think.)

```
var resultSearchController: UISearchController!()
```

Then, I had to add below.

```
self.resultSearchController.loadViewIfNeeded()
```

Comment: I just needed to add this code in the viewDidLoad()
before accessing the resultSearchController & it worked

Answer (score 1):

Just change following line

```
var resultSearchController = UISearchController()
```

to following line

```
var resultSearchController:UISearchController!
```

Your rest of the code is ok. Only that one change is required.

If you want to see detailed explanation then check my [tutorial on UISearchController](http://blog.apoorvmote.com/add-uisearchcontroller-to-tableview/)

Comment: Thank you. This fixed my constraint issue.